# Cypress: keep browser cache between runs

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I understand that Cypress by design starts each test run in a fresh browser session, with browser cache being empty. The new Session API allows persisting cookies, sessionStorage and localStorage - however, as far as I understand it does not permit keeping already loaded and cached static files and other fetched server resources.

Is there any way to make Cypress keep browser cache between runs - specifically static files?